# Localizing DateField output format in Django ModelForm

Tags: django, django-forms

Running Django 1.4.10. Trying to setup localization of dates in modelforms. Reading the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/i18n/formatting/#locale-aware-input-in-forms), it seems to be simply a case of setting localize=True attribute on your field in your ModelForm, and turning on localization in your settings. So, I do this:

```
my_field = DateField(localize=True)
```

in my form, and this in settings:

```
USE_L10N = True
```

Then we merrily go to the form, and it partially works. The Input format is localized, so for North America, it shows:

```
"m/d/y"
```

But the initial output format, when you first load the form, is in the default:

```
"y-m-d"
```

According to the docs, output localization should work as well as input localization. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do your templates look like? Are you using the localization template tags, for example?

Comment: @patrick beeson - My understanding is that wouldn't matter - it's an input form field, of which we need to display the initial output in a localized format, no?

Answer (score 6):

OK, answering my own question here, as I have it working. You need to supply the widget with the locale format for the output to be formatted as well. I presume this is a bug in Django. In any case, the field now becomes:

```
from django.utils import formats, translation

locale_format = formats.get_format('DATE_INPUT_FORMATS', lang=translation.get_language())[-1]
my_field = DateField(localize=True, widget=DateInput(format=locale_format))
```

The last entry in the locale_format list returns the short date format locale. No idea why it would do this.